# decimal point in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried to do a calculation in SQL Server and to retrieved value with 2 decimal point. However, this is always return me the value in 0 for the 2 decimal point. Does anyone know what is going on there?

example:

```
select convert(decimal(5,2),((2*100)/19), 2) as 'test'
from customer
```

The return is always 10.00 instead of 10.53

Comment: Not trying to be a smart alec, but I don't think you can ever get an answer of 10.53 on this one unless you're using a really messed up calculator.  Aren't you going for 105.26-ish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing one of the integers to a floating point number:

```
SELECT convert(decimal(5,2),((2*100.0)/19), 2) as 'test'
FROM customer
```

Result:

```
10.53
```

I picked 100 to change to 100.0 because I am guessing you are trying to calculate a percentage and that 100 will be a constant hardcoded in your final query. I am guessing that the other two values (2 and 19) will be later changed to read from integer fields in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Try to divide by 19.0 
If you just divide by 19, sql server assumes all the data types are integers and will do math accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select convert(decimal(5,2),((20*100)/19.0), 2) as 'test'
from customer
```

That little ".0" at the end of your denominator should help.